# GHCi derived type causes compile error when written manually

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following code below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

data Poly (c :: * -> Constraint) where
  Poly :: { getPoly :: (forall a. c a => a) } -> Poly c

type family Arg1 a where
  Arg1 (a -> _) = a

type family Result a where
  Result (_ -> a) = a

type IsOneArgFunc a = a ~ (Arg1 a -> Result a)

type NegateConstraint a = (IsOneArgFunc a, Real (Result a), Arg1 a ~ Result a)

class NegateConstraint a => NegateConstraintC a
instance NegateConstraint a => NegateConstraintC a

polyNegate :: Poly NegateConstraintC
polyNegate = Poly negate

testOp f x y = toRational (getPoly f x) == toRational (getPoly f y)

main = do
  print $ testOp polyNegate (2 :: Float) (2 :: Double)
```

(Note: parts are extracted from my [polydata](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polydata) and [indextype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/indextype) packages, but I've extracted the code below to avoid dependencies):

This compiles and runs perfectly fine.

Note that there is no type signature for `testOp`.

Loading this into `ghci` and asking `:t testOp` I get the following:

```
testOp
  :: (Real a1, Real a, c (t1 -> a1), c (t -> a)) =>
     Poly c -> t1 -> t -> Bool
```

Which seems like a reasonable type to derive. However, when I copy that into the code, like so:

```
testOp
  :: (Real a1, Real a, c (t1 -> a1), c (t -> a)) =>
     Poly c -> t1 -> t -> Bool
testOp f x y = toRational (getPoly f x) == toRational (getPoly f y)
```

I get a bunch of errors:

```
• Could not deduce (Real a0) arising from a use of ‘toRational’
  from the context: (Real a2, Real a, c (t1 -> a2), c (t -> a))
    bound by the type signature for:
               testOp :: (Real a2, Real a, c (t1 -> a2), c (t -> a)) =>
                         Poly c -> t1 -> t -> Bool
    at polyerror.hs:(31,1)-(33,30)
  The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Real Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    instance Real Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    instance Real Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    ...plus two others
    ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely
    ‘toRational (getPoly f x)’
  In the expression:
    toRational (getPoly f x) == toRational (getPoly f y)
  In an equation for ‘testOp’:
      testOp f x y = toRational (getPoly f x) == toRational (getPoly f y)

• Could not deduce: c (t1 -> a0) arising from a use of ‘getPoly’
  from the context: (Real a2, Real a, c (t1 -> a2), c (t -> a))
    bound by the type signature for:
               testOp :: (Real a2, Real a, c (t1 -> a2), c (t -> a)) =>
                         Poly c -> t1 -> t -> Bool
    at polyerror.hs:(31,1)-(33,30)
• In the first argument of ‘toRational’, namely ‘(getPoly f x)’
  In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘toRational (getPoly f x)’
  In the expression:
    toRational (getPoly f x) == toRational (getPoly f y)
• Relevant bindings include
    x :: t1 (bound at polyerror.hs:34:10)
    f :: Poly c (bound at polyerror.hs:34:8)
    testOp :: Poly c -> t1 -> t -> Bool (bound at polyerror.hs:34:1)

• Could not deduce (Real a1) arising from a use of ‘toRational’
  from the context: (Real a2, Real a, c (t1 -> a2), c (t -> a))
    bound by the type signature for:
               testOp :: (Real a2, Real a, c (t1 -> a2), c (t -> a)) =>
                         Poly c -> t1 -> t -> Bool
    at polyerror.hs:(31,1)-(33,30)
  The type variable ‘a1’ is ambiguous
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Real Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    instance Real Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    instance Real Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    ...plus two others
    ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely
    ‘toRational (getPoly f y)’
  In the expression:
    toRational (getPoly f x) == toRational (getPoly f y)
  In an equation for ‘testOp’:
      testOp f x y = toRational (getPoly f x) == toRational (getPoly f y)

• Could not deduce: c (t -> a1) arising from a use of ‘getPoly’
  from the context: (Real a2, Real a, c (t1 -> a2), c (t -> a))
    bound by the type signature for:
               testOp :: (Real a2, Real a, c (t1 -> a2), c (t -> a)) =>
                         Poly c -> t1 -> t -> Bool
    at polyerror.hs:(31,1)-(33,30)
• In the first argument of ‘toRational’, namely ‘(getPoly f y)’
  In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘toRational (getPoly f y)’
  In the expression:
    toRational (getPoly f x) == toRational (getPoly f y)
• Relevant bindings include
    y :: t (bound at polyerror.hs:34:12)
    f :: Poly c (bound at polyerror.hs:34:8)
    testOp :: Poly c -> t1 -> t -> Bool (bound at polyerror.hs:34:1)
```

Is there a type signature I can manually write for `testOp` that's generic as the inferred one, and if so, what is it? If not, is it by design that some functions you can not write a manual type signature for without losing generality, or is this a GHC bug (I'm currently using 8.0.2)?

Comment: Are you really sure this `AllowAmbiguousTypes` funk is a good idea?

Comment: Not particularly, but I'd appreciate a suggestion of how to get this to compile without it

Comment: @Clinton I'm not sure why it works in GHCi, but I think the GHC errors make sense. In order to pick an implementation of `toRational` it needs to know what type the result should be but there's nothing to indicate that. I'm thinking maybe you would need a `Proxy` argument or type application?

Comment: GHC compiled happily compiles and runs the code correctly without the signature also

Comment: @Clinton Perhaps without the type signature it is defaulting to some concrete `Real a`. I'm not sure how/why then GHCi reports the more general type, though.

Comment: I'm explicitly giving the types as Float and Double

Comment: @Clinton Are you? It seems like you are providing the types of `x` and `y`, but then calling `toRational` which is polymorphic in it's result. I don't think an implementation of `toRational` can be chosen with only that information?

Comment: 'toRational' is polymorphic in its input but not in its result

Comment: @Clinton Ah yes my mistake; sorry. I think the issue then is that `Poly`/`getPoly` specifically throws away the `Float`/`Double` type information. Isn't that what it's designed to do?

Comment: Poly is just intended to hold a polymorphic value. If you want to know how it's intended to work, just run it without the type signature. It works perfectly then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can give it that type signature, but you need to give it a few hints about how the types in the signature correspond with the expressions in the code. Turn on `ScopedTypeVariables`; then the following compiles:

```
testOp
  :: forall a1 a t1 t c.
     (Real a1, Real a, c (t1 -> a1), c (t -> a)) =>
     Poly c -> t1 -> t -> Bool
testOp f x y = toRational (getPoly f x :: a1) == toRational (getPoly f y :: a)
```

`toRational . getPoly f` is ambiguous for basically the same reason `show . read` is, and the solution here is analogous. For `show . read` you give a type signature somewhere that fixes `read`'s return type, and for your example I've given a type signature that fixes `getPoly f`'s return type.